# General definition of vector, spinor, and spin

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, vectors, representation-theory, spinors

I am looking for basic and exact definitions of fundamental physical concepts in graduate level.

I reach this following definitions. Could you please help to improve these definitions.

- Spin: Intrinsic degree of freedom for quantum particles and  obey angular momentum algebra.
- Spinor: Eigenstates of unitary groups
- Vector: Eigenstates of orthogonal groups
- Dirac Spinor: (operator? or eigenstate?) describes  spin 1/2 particles
- Weyl Spinor: (operator? or eigenstate?) describes  spin 1/2 massless particles (like neutrino?)
- Majorana Spinor:  (operator? or eigenstate?) describes spin 1/2 particles which have equal to own antiparticles.

Comment: I recently saw a lecture by Atiyah on spinors. He started by saying something along the lines of: "Nobody but God really knows what spinors are. And perhaps Dirac, but that doesn't change much."

Comment: @Danu Here it is: http://youtu.be/SBdW978Ii_E Watching it right now :)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41211/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 6):

Everything depends on how your fields (vectors and spinors are fields in the classical theory, and when you quantize in QFT, they become operator-valued fields) transform when you make a Lorentz transform:

- An **scalar** is a field that doesn't change at all: $\phi'(x') = \phi(x)$. Examples are the Higgs and pions.
- A **vector field** is a field that transform like a relativistic four-vector $A'_\mu (x') = {\Lambda^\nu}_\mu A_\nu(x)$, where $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation. Examples are the electromagnetic field (photons) and gluons.
- An **spinor field** transform using a different set of matrices $$\psi'(x') = \exp\left[(-i \vec{\theta} \pm\vec{\eta}) \cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}\right] \psi(x)$$ where $\vec{\theta}$ are the angles of rotation along the axes, $\vec{\eta}$ the rapidity and $\vec{\sigma}$ the Pauli matrices. As you can see, Pauli matrices are 2x2 matrices, so this transforms acts on objects with two components, the **Weyl spinors**. I have written two signs, $\pm$, because there are two types of transformations that act on two types of spinors: $-$ for *left-handed* spinors $\psi_L$ and $+$ for *right-handed* spinors $\psi_R$. But Weyl spinors have two problems: when you make a parity transformation ($\vec{r} \to -\vec{r}$), spinors change their *handeness*, and we know that QED and QCD are invariant under parity. And the other, as you say, is that Weyl fields must be massless.
- The **Dirac spinor** solves both problems. It is just (in the chiral representation) a left-handed and a right-handed Weyl spinors side-by-side $$\psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_L\\ \psi_R \end{pmatrix}$$ The Dirac spinor can have mass (although massless Dirac spinors are fine). Electrons, muons, taus, neutrinos and quarks are described Dirac fields.
- The **Majorana spinor** is a special Dirac spinor, where the left-handed and the right-handed parts are not independent. This relationship means that a Majorana particle is equal to its antiparticle. Therefore, the Majorana field has no electric charge. Although you only need one Weyl spinor to determine a Majorana spinor, Majorana fields still can have mass. It is conjectured that neutrinos might be Majorana particles (there are several experiments researching this).

So, where is spin? Angular momentum is a conserved quantity related to rotations. Whe you apply Nöther's theorem to a field, you get two terms: one depends on the movement of the particles (the orbital angular moment) and the other not (the **spin**). The spin part is related to the type of Lorentz transform that the field uses: in scalar fields there is no spin term (they have spin 0), in spinor fields it is a representation of rotations of dimension 2 (spin 1/2), and in vector fields a representation of rotations of dimension 3 (spin 1).