# Why is a spinor not a tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, representation-theory, spinors

The title says it. why is a spinor not a tensor? I know the transformation rules for a spinor but I cant see why it is not a tensor?

Comment: Tensors are defined by their transformation rules, hence they cannot be. Although both are sections of vector bundles, and there is a mapping from spinors to tensors.

Comment: A tensor is made up out of direct products of the defining/vector representation, but a spinor is not: it constitutes a distinct representation not reachable from the vector one. So, typically, composing integral spin objects will never yield a half-integral object to you.

Comment: Wait: a spinor is defined as an element of a vector space (more precisely, as an element of a representation of a double cover of $SO(n)$). It is therefore a vector. Doesn't that make it a rank 0 tensor?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41211/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766673/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605707/226902 Possibile answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/554283/226902